# Unable to change 'Default External Access' in Sharing Settings

Tags: sharing, access

According to the Optimizer report, we should immediately change the default external access for more than 100 objects.

However, if I go to Sharing Settings and click Edit (which is the way to go according to the [help documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.security_sharing_owd_users.htm&type=5)), I can only change the internal access, not the external access. Almost - but not all(!) - external access entries are not editable. I am the sysadmin of the org (with the default system administrator profile).

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably this org has been around a while? So my guess is based on this [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.security_owd_external_setting.htm&type=5) that says:

> Before you set the external organization-wide defaults, make sure that
> they’re enabled. From Setup, in the Quick Find box, enter Sharing
> Settings, then select Sharing Settings, and click the Enable External
> Sharing Model button. External organization-wide defaults are
> automatically enabled in all orgs created in Spring ’20 or after and
> in all orgs where Salesforce Experiences or portals are enabled.

Comment: Thank you! Because I could see the settings, I never imagined that something had to be enabled in order to change them. So I never looked for a setting and I completely overlooked that button. And yes, clicking that button enables me to change the settings.